# Specifying zip file for batch execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, selection, minecraft, 7zip

so im pretty new to batch here and im attempting to make an auto installer for some modifications that need to be done to a jar.

it will execute when i drag the file over but im not sure how to tell it to execute the file wihtout draggin it over and dropping

so you know the 7za app is used to extract and as i said this works if i drag and drop for the file i want forge.zip to unpack and inject into the minecraft.jar

```
set_source=%APPDATA%\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\forge.zip
set path="%USERPROFILE%";%path%
move 7za.exe %USERPROFILE%
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za x AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
7za x %* -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\ -y
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
rmdir /S /Q META-INF
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
ren minecraft.jar "minecraft_c.jar"
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za a -r minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft     \bin\TempStuff\* -o%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
rmdir /S /Q TempStuff
cd %USERPROFILE%
move /y %USERPROFILE%\minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
pause
```

this is supposed to overwrite the core files in a jar to allow for the modified ones. to take hold yes i did look at soemone elses replace code but i think i screwed up somewhere... :(

solution

```
set path="%USERPROFILE%";%path%
move 7za.exe %USERPROFILE%
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za x AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
7za x "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\JarMods\*.zip" -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\ -y
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
rmdir /S /Q META-INF
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
ren minecraft.jar "minecraft_c.jar"
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za a -r minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\* -o%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
rmdir /S /Q TempStuff
cd %USERPROFILE%
move /y %USERPROFILE%\minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
cd %APPDATA%\Roaming\.minecraft
mkdir mods
move "%USERPROFILE%\<insert ModInstall path here>\OtherMods\"       %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
```

Comment: figured it out here is the new code using 7za

Comment: then you should post the solution as an answer and mark as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The author came up with the solution but hasn't been back to SO since, so his solution is now going to be put in here:

```
set path="%USERPROFILE%";%path%
move 7za.exe %USERPROFILE%
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za x AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
7za x "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\JarMods\*.zip" -oAppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\ -y
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\
rmdir /S /Q META-INF
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
ren minecraft.jar "minecraft_c.jar"
cd %USERPROFILE%
7za a -r minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\TempStuff\* -o%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
rmdir /S /Q TempStuff
cd %USERPROFILE%
move /y %USERPROFILE%\minecraft.jar %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin
cd %APPDATA%\Roaming\.minecraft
mkdir mods
move "%USERPROFILE%\<insert ModInstall path here>\OtherMods\"       %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
```